# Exchange Server Smart Host not working

Tags: windows, email, exchange, smtp

I have 2 Server, let me illustration like this
**Server A = Exchange Server**
**Server B = SMTP Server(Postfix) on VPS**
I want my Server A fully **Sending&Receiving Email** from **Server B(Because Server A Port 25 is Blocked By ISP)**
So i connected **Server A Smart Host** to **Server B SMTP**
But when i check my **mailing logs**, **Server A** doesn't use Server B SMTP for **sending/receiving Email**
So i can't **Email to External/Internet Email**, but my **Server B SMTP is working normally** 
There is some configuration in my Servers, and Logs.
**Server A Domain = mail.fendyfy.com**
**Server B Domain = smtp.fendyfy.com**
Smarthost Configuration: https://imgur.com/1k62LQQ
DNS Configuration: https://imgur.com/6hMmQDn
Domain Hosting Configuration: https://imgur.com/a/nWbfUq8
Exchange Server Logs: https://imgur.com/YeRMlMw
SMTP Testing(Worked): https://imgur.com/ed3z8N7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, an Exchange server will try and send emails to a smart host using port 25. Since your Server A(Exchange Server) port 25 got blocked, you need to change this to a different port number, follow this [steps](https://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/change-exchange-smart-host-port-number/) to configure it:

```
Set-SendConnector -identity "smart host connector" -Port:587
```

For more details on [creating a Send connector to route outbound mail through a smart host.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/connectors/outbound-smart-host-routing?view=exchserver-2019)

Comment: great, thankyou so much, you made my day :)